# Index exception in 2D

Tags: c++, exception, matrix

I have a problem with the following. I implement matrices. There is a class for entire matrix and a class for one row of matrix. I have created Rows in order to I could access members like that matrix[a][b]. But the problem is with throwing exception which must be in format like that "Invalid index [e][f]". I would use try-catch in matrix overload [] and throwing integer exception from Rows overload [],but it do not solve case when the first index is ok and the second one is wrong.

```
//Matrix overload
Row& operator [] (unsigned inx) {
return *rows[inx];
}

//Row overload
double& operator [] (unsigned inx) 
{
return items[inx];
}
```

Comment: you cant overload just the return type. Overloading needs a different signature.

Comment: Let the `Row` object keep track of the index that it's associated with.

Comment: @Freddy They're implemented in different classes. Yeah, it's not totally clear from the question.

Comment: Just throw from the `Row operator[]` and rethrow from `Matrix operator[]`?

Answer (score 1):

> exception must be in format like "Invalid index [e][f]"

That's trickier than it sounds!

**If `[f]` is invalid, `Matrix::operator[]( e )` has already finished.  That parameter is no longer available.**

So you will need to pass this information to the `Row` in question at some point.  Here is one way.

```
// (Member variable "int Row::index" is added...)

//Matrix overload
Row& operator [] (unsigned inx) {
  rows[inx]->setRowIndex(inx);
  return *rows[inx];
}

//Row overload
double& operator [] (unsigned inx) 
{
  // Now you can throw information about both inx and the stored row index
  return items[inx];
}
```

**If `[e]` is invalid, `Row::operator[]( f )` hasn't been called yet.  It's an unknown value.**

That means that even when `[e]` is invalid, it must return something that `operator[]` can still be called on before throwing.

```
// (Member variable "bool Row::isInvalid" is added...)

//Matrix overload
Row& operator [] (unsigned inx) {
  Row *result;
  if ( inx is invalid ) 
  {
     // Don't throw yet!
     static Row dummy;
     dummy.setInvalid();
     result = &dummy;
  }
  else
  {
    result = rows[inx];
  }
  result->setRowIndex(inx);
  return *result;
}

//Row overload
double& operator [] (unsigned inx) 
{
  // If this->isInvalid is true, the first index was bad.
  // If inx is invalid, the second index was bad.
  // Either way, we have both indices now and may throw!
  return items[inx];
}
```